# Stylesheet is not saving

Tags: css

I am using Dreamweaver CS 6 for creating my website, but apparently my stylesheet is somehow not saving anymore. I save it, it is uploading it via  FTP to the hosting site, but there are no changes. In the live-view in Dreamweaver I can see the changes.
Any other changes on the normal HTML page are done immediatly after upload.
Thanks for any help
Chris

Comment: You can always try you site in private browsing, no cache

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your browser cache.  You can do that by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `delete` in your web browser and selecting `delete cache`.  If you are using an older version of Internet Explorer you will need to go to tools->Internet Options and delete it there.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can add some characters to the end of the file where you load it:

```
 <link href='your_css_file?1234' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then when a user who has the file cached try to load, the new file will be returned.